# CSS border animation wobbling on HDPI screens, box-sizing problem?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

Problem: a loading animation wobbled on my screen, why?

*...Here is my screenrecording (tried to convert mov to gif, hope it works...) ->*

[image]

**Here is the demo:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index?autoRun=true&theme=bootstrap-main">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.301/styles/kendo.bootstrap-main.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.301/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.301/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    
    

</head>
<body>
    <div id="example" role="application">
    <div class="demo-section k-content">
      
      <style>
        [aria-controls=notwobbling_listbox] .k-icon.k-i-loading::before{
          width: 15px;
          height: 15px;
        }
      </style>
      
      <input id="wobbling" style="width: 140px; transform: scale(3); margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 140px" />
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input id="notwobbling" style="width: 140px; transform: scale(3); margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 140px" />
      
      
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#wobbling").kendoMultiSelect({
        placeholder: "...",
        filter: "contains",
        dataTextField: "txtb",
        dataValueField: "txta",
        maxSelectedItems: 1,
        placeholder: 'wobbling',
        dataSource: {
            transport:{
                read: function(options){
                    
                }
            }
        },
    });
          
                     $("#notwobbling").kendoMultiSelect({
        placeholder: "...",
        filter: "contains",
        dataTextField: "txtb",
        dataValueField: "txta",
        maxSelectedItems: 1,
        placeholder: 'not wobbling',
        dataSource: {
            transport:{
                read: function(options){
                    
                }
            }
        },
    });
        $(".k-i-loading").addClass("k-input-loading-icon");
        });
    </script>
</div>


    

</body>
</html>
```

Looks like I could fix it by adding .k-icon.k-i-loading::before {width: 15px; height: 15px;} but I don't see the sizes being a problem ...
Maybe it's the box-sizing...

Comment: For me, the not-wobbling one is wobbling and the other one looks fine.

Comment: Have to use a retina mac like 14". What are you using?